# Cannot find module 'at-least-node'

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Unable to load Platform API from /Users/RK/Documents/IONIC/ionic/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/Api.js:
Cannot find module 'at-least-node'

making ios build in ionic 3.4

Comment: You should mark the below as accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure the magic that fixed it for me:

- delete `/node_modules`, `/platforms`, `/plugins`, **`/package-lock.json`**
- re-run troubled command(s)

---

But here are all the things I did (incase it was a different thing that actually fixed it)....

Windows:

- Upgrading node from 12.14.0 -> 15.x
- delete node_modules, platforms, plugins, package-lock.json
- re-run troubled command(s)

  - *success!*

Mac:

- Upgrading node from 12.14.0 -> 14.15.0  (probably didn't actually matter)
- delete node_modules, platforms, plugins
- re-run troubled command(s)

  - *failed*
- delete node_modules, platforms, plugins, **package-lock.json**
- **Restart computer (mac)**
- re-run troubled command(s)

  - *success!*

All are on Cordova 9.0.0 and node 14+.
Received this error when installing plugins usually.
Got the error for building ios and android.

Comment: I can confirm that removing the package-lock.json file was the magic. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much. This issue was show stopper for us but after following your steps, it's working like a charm. These are the steps which we follow 1. Delete following folders 
 platforms
 node_modules
 plugins
 package-lock.json

Run following commands stap by stap
1. npm install
2. ionic cordova platform add android